# Не считываются клавиши / SFML KeyBoard event

Tags: c++, sfml

Есть код:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(600, 600), "Test");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }
    window.clear(Color(i, i, i));

    if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed)
    {
        if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Q)
        {
            i +=10;
            std::cout << i;
        }
        if (event.key.code == Keyboard::E)
        {
            i -= 10;
            std::cout << i;
        }
    }
    window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ничего не происходит при нажатии на Q, но если вместо "Q" написать Left - то всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: Приведите [mre]

Comment: Раскладка английская.

Comment: event следует смотреть после успешного poll

Comment: Переместил проверку нажатия в цикл while (window.pollEvent(event)) и заработало. Спасибо!